# Visual Studio 2017 not offering quick actions

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-core, nuget-package, visual-studio-2017

I created a new ASP.NET Core project in my brand new installation of VS2017:

I open Startup.cs, I create a ctor method and inside it I write:

```
var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
```

I don't even finish the line with a semicolon and a yellow lightbulb appears on the left, it's VS offering me a quick action to add

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
```

That's what I consider a normal VS behavior.

However, just a few lines down, when I'm trying to AddMvc() in the ConfigureServices() method, no lightbulb, no quick actions are being offered.
So when I type the following:

```
services.AddMvc();
```

I'm stuck with an error, until I "manually" open Nuget package manager and explicitly add Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc

I had no such problems in VS2015, because I was always offered a yellow lightbulb, after which I hit CTRL+. and then Enter to download the right files.

Here's how my VS17 relevant options look like: 
USING DIRECTIVES
[image: UsingDirectives]

NUGET GENERAL
[image: NugetGeneral]

NUGET PACKAGE SOURCES
[image: NugetPackageSources]

Anybody else having the same problem?
I installed VS17 on my friend's PC (she kindly let me) and it's all the same there. No light bulb to automatically suggest me downloading a Nuget.

Comment: I'm not sure this will do what you want, but try this. go to Options -> Text Editor > C# -> Advanced -> "Suggest usings for types in NuGet packages" it's the closest option I can find related to this.

Comment: Unfortunately, that wasn't it :(  There's still no quick action light bulb appearing on the line that would need additional nuget package...

Comment: +dman2306 This is weird. What you suggested is supposed to work, since I found something very close to your advice cited on VS2017 blog post, BUT IT DOESN'T work on my machine...what the...

Comment: @PaxForce did you ever find the solution to this?  I'm going through some tutorials and they simply say "use the shortcut for blah" but if it doesn't work there's no way to know what package to use. Very frustrating.

Comment: Having the same issue. Still doesn't work even after I change the text editor settings...